# Java setOnAction subscribe to event that throws exception

Tags: java, events, javafx

Let me preface this by saying, I am not a Java programmer and have thus far been unable to understand WHY this is the case.

I'm currently working on a homework assignment that requires me to create a basic GUI using JavaFX. The functionality of this GUI requires that there are buttons that will perform CRUD operations when clicked. Currently I have everything set up properly in my Insert method:

```
        public void Insert() throws SQLException{

        //Insert new record here
    }
```

However, whenever I try to subscribe to this method using 'setOnAction', the compiler is telling me there's an unhandled exception on the event:

```
btnInsert.setOnAction(e ->Insert());
```

I'm more curious if there's a way to handle this in a relatively succinct way? I've thus far been unable to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because Java requires you to declare all checked exceptions you throw - so whenever you call a method that may throw a checked exception, you must either catch it or declare you may throw it yourself.

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115896/java-checked-vs-unchecked-exception-explanation) for an explanation of checked vs. unchecked exception (The short version - any Exception which inherits either `Error` or `RuntimeException` is unchecked, while all other exceptions are checked.)

When you are providing `setOnAction` with a lambda, you are actually creating an anonymous class implementation of [`EventHandler<ActionEvent>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/event/EventHandler.html). Since it does not declare it throws any exceptions, neither does your anonymous class (and in fact - it can't).

So you have two options of solving the problem:

1. Catch and handle the exception:

   ```
   btnInsert.setOnAction(e -> {
       try {
           Insert();
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           // Log error, show error message, etc... Whichever is applicable for your application
       }
   });
   ```
2. Rethrow an un-checked exception:

   ```
   btnInsert.setOnAction(e -> {
       try {
           Insert();
       } catch (SQLException ex) {
           throw new RuntimeException(ex); // Or any other subclass of RuntimeException or Error
       }
   });
   ```

As to choosing between the two options - [Oracle's documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/runtime.html) says this:

> Here's the bottom line guideline: If a client can reasonably be expected to recover from an exception, make it a checked exception. If a client cannot do anything to recover from the exception, make it an unchecked exception.

Of course, this could all be moved away from the actual `EventHandler`, so it can be called on a method that is checked-exception-free.

Comment: Thank you. This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for.